# XSLT to remove SOAP envelope but leave namespaces

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to remove soap envelope from soap message. For that I want to use XSLT, not java. It would be more proper solution for operating such type of xml.

For e.g. I have a soap message:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                  xmlns:tar="namespace" 
                  xmlns:tar1="namespace">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <tar:RegisterUser>
            <tar1:Source>?</tar1:Source>
            <tar1:Profile>
                <tar1:EmailAddress>?</tar1:EmailAddress>

            </tar1:Profile>
        </tar:RegisterUser>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And I want my output to be something like this:

```
<tar:RegisterUser xmlns:tar="namespace" xmlns:tar1="namespace">
    <tar1:Source>?</tar1:Source>
    <tar1:Profile>
        <tar1:EmailAddress>?</tar1:EmailAddress>

    </tar1:Profile>
</tar:RegisterUser>
```

Can someone provide me with some ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This gets rid of the `soapenv:` elements *and* the namespace declaration.

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
>
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="soapenv:*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<tar:RegisterUser xmlns:tar="namespace">
  <tar1:Source xmlns:tar1="namespace">?</tar1:Source>
  <tar1:Profile xmlns:tar1="namespace">
    <tar1:EmailAddress>?</tar1:EmailAddress>
  </tar1:Profile>
</tar:RegisterUser>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/*"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tar:RegisterUser xmlns:tar="namespace" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tar1="namespace">
    <tar1:Source>?</tar1:Source>
    <tar1:Profile>
        <tar1:EmailAddress>?</tar1:EmailAddress>
    </tar1:Profile>
</tar:RegisterUser>
```

Unfortunately, I could not find any easy way to remove the `xmlns:soapenv` attribute.

Comment: To remove the unnecessary namespace declaration, add the `exclude-result-namespaces="soapenv"` attribute to `<xsl:stylesheet>`

Comment: I tried that, but Saxon, Xalan and MSXML, all still included the namespace.

Comment: Oops, that would be `exclude-result-prefixes="soapenv"`, of course. But you are right, the namespace stays in because of the `<xsl:copy-of>`. See my solution for a more elegant way that removes both the envelope and the namespace.